# Http status 404: Not found error on File Upload

Tags: c#, .net

The file i'm uploading is 55MB. Max file size allowed is 49MB. My code is:

```
private void AddFilePartToVault(FileInfo fileInfo, long folderId, 
                                WebServiceManager manager)
{
    Guid guid = Guid.Empty;

    using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileInfo.FullName,
                               FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
    {

        ByteArray array = new ByteArray();
        array.Bytes= new byte[MaxFileSize];

        long unreadBytes;
        while ((unreadBytes = stream.Length-stream.Position)>0)
        {

           if (unreadBytes < MaxFileSize)
           array.Bytes=new byte[unreadBytes];

            stream.Read(array.Bytes,0,array.Bytes.Length);
            try
            {
                guid = manager.DocumentService.UploadFilePart(guid, array);
            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException we)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(we.Message);
            }
       }
```

Using this, the second part of 6MB is uploaded and the first 49MB is not uploaded. Throws wen exception Http status 404 Not found.

Comment: What is the value of `unreadBytes` in the attempt that fails? Perhaps 404 is the server's way of saying it received an invalid upload request.

Comment: It is 49MB i.e the MaxFileSize in the first iteration. In the second iteration, it is the remaining 6 MB.